Laravel 11 Validation digits_between on negative integer values not working
I am trying to submit a simple form with laravel.  I have the following rule and when I enter '-100' or any other negative number, the validation fails.
'odds' => ['integer', 'digits_between:3,70'],
results in:

The odds field must be between 3 and 70 digits.

From the Laravel 11.x docs,

The integer validation must have a length between the given min and max.

Why is the validation failing when -100 is only 4 characters in length?  I tried other integers such as -1000, -14000, -10, etc. and it seems like any negative integer gets rejected.
The field is also:
<input type="number" name="odds">
Would anyone have an idea why the laravel validation fails?
Also tried:
``'odds' => ['numeric', 'digits_between:3,70'],`

Use between:min,max
example : 'field_name' => ['required', 'numeric', 'between:-100,100']
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#rule-between

Create a Custom Validation Rule:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

    class DigitsBetweenInclusive implements Rule
    {
        protected $min;
        protected $max;
    
        public function __construct($min, $max)
        {
            $this->min = $min;
            $this->max = $max;
        }
    
        public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            $length = strlen((string) abs($value));
            return $length >= $this->min && $length <= $this->max;
        }
    
        public function message()
        {
            return 'The :attribute must be an integer with digits between ' . $this->min . ' and ' . $this->max . '.';
        }
    }

Use the Custom Rule in Your Validation:
use App\Rules\DigitsBetweenInclusive;

$request->validate([
    'odds' => ['integer', new DigitsBetweenInclusive(3, 70)],
]);

This should work properly.

Thanks, I experimented with this route and it does indeed work properly.  I decided to choose Aakash's route since its a bit easier to implement.
